# I get Killed by signal 15. when I'm using svn

Tags: ssh, svn, signals

I'm using svn+ssh and I see a number of:

`Killed by signal 15.`

during a `svn up`.

Any ideas way?

Comment: There are a large number of hits for http://www.google.com/search?q=svn+signal+15 looking through them there does seem to be a known bug for older versions of subversion that require you to update your .subversion/config http://old.nabble.com/svn%2Bssh----Killed-by-signal-15.-td26226917.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message you are seeing is printed by ssh as a result of the fix for [svn-issue #2580](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-2580).

This is expected. You need to add `-q` to the ssh command invoked by svn, which happens by default as of 1.6.6.

Put this in `~/.subversion/config` under the `[tunnels]` section:

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
```

Comment: To make the solution work, you should put the line into [tunnels] section

Comment: Note that the fix applied to Subversion somewhere from about 1.6.5 onwards is only to the default `ssh` setting in your config `[tunnels]` section. If you have an existing installation with that set, e.g. `ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no`, (sans `-q`) then you will need to add that setting there, as the updated default will not apply.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is:

```
Add the -q parameter after  "$SVN_SSH ssh" in ~/.subversion/config
```

In plain English:

If your ~/.subversion/config already has such a line, then edit the line. Else add it.

So, if you are sure there is no occurrence of **ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh** then add a new line:

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
```

If the line already exists, typically as `ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no`  then edit it to read `ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -o ControlMaster=no`

**Warning:** The order of the parameters seems to matter. `ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -o ControlMaster=no` works, but `ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o -q ControlMaster=no` fails with the message *command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: -q*.

Comment: The order matters because 'ControlMaster=no' is a parameter of -o. -o is not a stand-alone flag

Answer (score 0):

```
 ~/.subversion/config: ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
```

This doesn't work - I think this is the fix for the *previous* bug.

```
[n@g ~]$ svn up /opt/
At revision 1492.
Killed by signal 15.
[n@g ~]$ grep "ssh =" ~/.subversion/config
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
```

Answer (score 0):

If it isnt working perhaps you are invoking ssh using something other than the $SVN_SSH variable.  http://www.freebsdonline.com/content/view/764/528/ has an example of that.

regarding the warning:

> "Warning: The order of the parameters seems to matter. ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -o ControlMaster=no works, but ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o -q ControlMaster=no fails with the message command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: -q."

that is because you placed the -q after the -o which is looking for the option (ControlMaster=no) specified by -o.  if you placed the -q after the option, it will work. ie

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no -q
```